# Semantic of statement for in the initialization area when I use let declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know that when I declare a let variable in a loop the variable is declared in each cycle. For instance:

```
for(let i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)
{
    let x=1;
}
```

The variable `x` is declared 3 times namely are allocated three different places in the memory for each variable in the loop.

However what does it happen to the variable `i`? Is it declared once?
Or is it initialized one time alone but is declared three times too?

I would like to understand what it happens behind the scene.

Comment: `i` is declared once, `x` is declared again, but don't worry about it..  Internally the V8 engine, or whatever engine you browser is using, will optimise `x`..

Comment: Also local to the loop's block's environments, aka also three variable creations for `i` in this case.

Comment: Note: not directly a dupe of, but very related - [javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `let`, `i` is declared once and gets a fresh binding for every cycle. And its scope is only visible inside of the block statement.

From here [Variables and scoping in ECMAScript 6](https://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html#let-in-loop-heads):

> `let` in loop heads
>
> In loops, you get a fresh *binding* for each iteration if you `let`-declare a variable. The loops that allow you to do so are: `for`, `for-in` and `for-of`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let x = 1;
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000);
}
```

Another example with an **assignment** for having a fresh binding.

```js
for (let x = { v: 0 }; x.v < 2; x.v += 1) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(x), 100); // same values
}

for (let x = { v: 0 }; x.v < 2; x = { v: x.v + 1}) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(x), 100); // different values
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Are you sure?, what you have created here with your `setTimeout` is a closure, and from what I can gather that will be only created when required, if `i` is not used this way, then no closure is required.  I'd be very surprised if V8's engine created a closure when one wasn't required.

Comment: Thus, i is declared again and initialized again with the value in the "increment section (i++)".

Comment: Why is the `i` declaration executed multiple times ? According to https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp the first statement  "is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block."

Comment: I thought you could test this using the comma operator (something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gfj8z06v/) maybe), it says it is initialized once?

Comment: @MickaelB. Please do not use w3schools as reference for anything that goes beyond the basics of the basics. See [meta topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com). They are not a good source.

Comment: `i` is always new for each cycle. it is called *fresh binding*.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, otherwise this wouldn't work -> `for (let x={v:0}; x.v < 10; x.v += 1) { console.log(x);}`  unless maybe the browser is making it into a `const`,..   Anyway, seems very wasteful doing a copy, when not required.

Comment: @NickParsons the value is copied over, the initialization is not done again, see [13.7.4.9 Runtime Semantics: CreatePerIterationEnvironment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createperiterationenvironment)

Comment: @ASDFGerte Didn't knew thanks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for says the same thing that the initialization is "evaluated once before the loop begins"

Comment: @Keith "*from what I can gather that will be only created when required*" - engine optimisations don't change how things work in general. You could also say that the `let x = 1` does not create a variable (because `x` is never used and optimised out) although it arguably does.

Comment: @Bergi  So is `for (let x={v:0};` doing a full copy of the object on each iteration?.  Or is the `{v:0}` is static in memory, and what's happening here is that a new `x` is getting re-assigned to the old `{v:0}`.  The reason I also believe closures are created when required, do 2 setTimeouts with different wait times, you will still get `1,2,3` implying there was 2 closures created, not just one.  So making the closure a the block level of the let definition only would fail.

Comment: @Keith, it is a problem of the assignment. if directly a new scope is created and if just the same value is used, then it shares the same value.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, doesn't your `same values` prove here that `let x={v:0}` is indeed NOT getting a fresh binding.  It's certainly running like it's not!!,. with the result been `2 2`, it appears to be the same bindings.  IOW: x is the same x that was used at the start of the `for` and the subsequent setTimeouts.

Comment: in the first example `x` keeps it old value (only a property changes). In the second `x` gets a new assignment.

Comment: @Keith Objects are never "fully copied". An object is a reference value, and when you do `x_1 = x_0` then nothing but the reference is copied into the other variable.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answers. But I'm still a bit confused. When i declare a variable with let in the body of a for (for-in and for-of too) happens like with a call function namely a new execution context is created with its own variable object and scope chain thus the x variable is redeclared (like if was redeclared). And the same should be for let i in the initialization of the for, rather @NinaScholz said that i is declared once. Furthemore I don't understand why in the first case of the second example you get the same value; being x declared with let I would have expected 0 1 too.

Comment: @Umbert, x has never changed with an direct assignment. the result is like using `var`.

Comment: @NinaScholz I saw that. Therefore each iteration require a new LexicalBinding only if there is a fresh value for the variable declared with let otherwise no.  Can you confirm? Sorry in the case  I had said a nonsense

Comment: right, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is declared every cycle if you use `let`.

`i` is declared once if you use `var`.

`i` is not declared every cycle if you use `const` (it has the same scope as the loop). Try this and you will get an error:

```
for (const i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   // more statements
}
```

> error: Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Extratos_e_declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es/for).

Comment: But the error here is the i++, namely the modify to a const variable.

Comment: @Umbert , you are correct and I've edited my answer.